# Is it a good think to solve an equation by just changing the sign of number after moving it to the other side?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the equation $x+3=9$

The method is to add $-3$ to both members of the equations and get $$x-3=9-3, ~~~~~~~x=6$$
but in my last year book and my last year teacher teached it us another method (derived from this) is that we can change the number side by changing its sign.

Consider $x+3=9$ again,
$+3$ becomes $-3$
$x=9-3$
$x=6$

But this year teacher does not let us use this method without stating any reason, is there a reason?

Comment: IMHO, your current teacher is a new bit too ... In any event, just do what your current teacher ask you to do in his/her class and outside class, forget what he/she forces you to do.

Comment: "teacher does not let us use this method without stating any reason": sorry, but this is hard to believe. Maybe a misunderstanding ?

Comment: she simply tell us dont use this! use only what I tell you! this will make you confused! do you find this a reason?

Comment: I still suspect a misunderstanding.

Comment: It's not a misunderstanding, look we were doing an exercice in a polynome chapter and we got and exercice to solve equations.She did a review to how we solve equations and we told us that we change number side by changing its side she said a big No even thought I argued her that it is the same thing

Comment: Imho, its good that she only allows you to apply a method if you can give a reason for why it is valid.

Comment: I told her its the same thing a is parameter and x the unknown: ax +b=c; ax+b-b=c-b;ax=c-b

Answer (score 1):

It's the same exact method, it just looks a bit different. The "Subtract $3$ from each side, then simplify away $3-3$ on the left" way of thinking is the original one. The "move $3$ to the other side and make it $-3$" interpretation is derived from that by noting that they give the same end result. If they always give the same end result, and one of them is valid, then the other must be valid as well.

However, it could be worth noting why any of them are valid in the first place. And the reason for that is that if you have two things which were originally equal (which is what the $=$ symbol means), then they stay equal after subtracting $3$ from each of them.

That being said, there is a small point to placating your teacher. If your teacher has a certain hang-up, then going against that is a fight you will probably lose. If all you have to do in order to be allowed to use this maneuver is to give a reason for why it's valid, then try to do that. But if your teacher hates it and marks it as incorrect every time you use it, then I personally wouldn't think it was a fight worth fighting.

Answer (score 1):

I learned the move to the other side and switch sign method first.

I'd argue the move and switch method is better.

First as mentioned before it is exactly as valid as the usual method.

Second, the usual method has you doing two subtractions. The move and switch method cognitively and visually has you doing only one. You get the job done with less Cognitive Load.

I think most people who are good in algebra have learned this trick along the way so problems are a little easier and math is less frustrating.

Your teacher might mark it off if you do it this way. It's your teacher that's making the mistake if it is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is exactly what you just wrote. Substract $3$ from both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add or subtract the same quantity from both sides of an equation.

$$x+3=9\iff x+3\color{green}{-3}=9\color{green}{-3}\iff x=9-3$$

The "two" methods you describe are a single one.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten the idea precisely correct. The "subtract from both sides" is where the method comes from, but once you use it enough, it will become so automatic in your mind that you don't even have to think about it. But still you will remember the original method.

The teacher might be "insisting" on using the "more rigorous" method so that nobody gets confused, but as long as you know what you're doing and get equations solved and be comfortable with it, that's the main point in my opinion.